# How does the windows file system works?

Tags: windows, documentation, filesystems

I am working on a project that uses a filesystem and I'm having some problems integrating with Windows.

I need help understanding how the Windows file system works.

Comment: NTFS, FAT, FAT32, UDF, ...? there are many filesystems supported by Windows.

Comment: I think I don't was clear.
I need know how windows handle the events with file system.

My project uses Dokan library.
We have some problems with large files. Probably why we do not know how to treat some events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean NTFS. Then the best reference is http://www.ntfs.com/

A friend of mine started implementing a [defragmenter](http://code.google.com/p/msdefrag/) based on that information and it appears to work properly. That means the info from that site seems reliable.

Answer (score 2):

Which Windows? The file system used by DOS and Windows up to Win98 (if I am not mistaken) is FAT. It is still widely used e.g. by memory cards, digital cameras etc. Windows NT and later Windows versions however use NTFS.

You may start reading about [FAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) and [NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) on Wikipedia.